# Android with visual studio 2017 - build.gradle vs build.gradle.template

Tags: android, visual-studio, gradle, build.gradle

So I'm trying to build an Android app using Visual Studio. I started with a project created from the 'New Project' wizard ('Basic Application (Android, Gradle)'). I'm having trouble understanding how the build.gradle and build.gradle.template files relate to each other. The build.gradle file doesn't even show in the VS solution explorer until I enable 'show all files'. And when I make changes to build.gradle, they seem to be overwritten (sometimes?) upon build. Should I only edit build.gradle.template? What build step or tool processes this file to create the final build.gradle? Does the same apply to AndroidManifest.xml.template?

And what about gradle-wrapper - is gradle-wrapper.properties the same as gradle.properties? (I had to add the location of my JDK in there to get builds from the command line, outside VS, to work - so I just created my own gradle.properties but now I'm not sure if there are multiple parts doing the same thing, potentially stepping on each other).

Comment: but where do i find the build.gradle file? 
I selected Show All files 
Still it did not show the build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

The build.grade is generated by Visual Studio, from the build.gradle.template before it actually runs Gradle. This is true for the AndroidManifest.xml.template as well.

You should not edit the .gradle or .xml file itself and preferably not include it in your source control.

As for the wrapper, I can't really answer.

Comment: but where do i find the build.gradle file?

Comment: Visual Studio will generate it in the same directory as the template file. You might want to turn on "show all files" in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

build your solution first , gradle will download necessary files on vs 2017 ..

good god at all the bullsh! answers !

this will fix it , or simply open a command prompt and type gradle -v if your gradle path has been set.

result

```
1>:app:assembleArm7Release
1>
1>BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>
1>Total time: 1 mins 24.553 secs
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```